# django-allauth signin with google redirects to development url even in production

Tags: django, google-oauth, django-allauth

I created a Client ID and Client Secret from [the google cloud api console](https://cloud.google.com/console) and added a record in the Social apps table for `django-allauth`

I also added `WEB ORIGIN`:

1. `mysite.com`                 (prod)
2. `http://localhost:8000`      (dev)

and `REDIRECT URI`

1. `http:mysite.com/accounts/google/login/callback/`     (prod)
2. `localhost:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/`      (dev)

in the google api console.

Sign in with Google works great in development and redirects to the localhost callback url on successful sign-in. But I'm getting a `redirect_uri_mismatch` error in prod.

These are the error details from the google error page:

**Request Details**

```
cookie_policy_enforce=false
scope=https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email
response_type=code
access_type=online
redirect_uri=http://127.0.0.1:8000/accounts/google/login/callback/
state=SOME_RANDOM_NUMBER
display=page
client_id=MY_CLIENT_ID
```

The `redirect_uri` is still set to `127.0.0.1` instead of `http:mysite.com/accounts/google/login/callback/`

**So how do I set the proper `redirect_uri`?**

This is my `settings.py` pertaining to `django-allauth`

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
    #the usual stuff
    'allauth',
    'allauth.account',
    'allauth.socialaccount',
    'allauth.socialaccount.providers.google',
)

import django.conf.global_settings as DEFAULT_SETTINGS

TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS = DEFAULT_SETTINGS.TEMPLATE_CONTEXT_PROCESSORS + (
    "allauth.account.context_processors.account",
    "allauth.socialaccount.context_processors.socialaccount",
)

AUTHENTICATION_BACKENDS = (
    "django.contrib.auth.backends.ModelBackend",
    "allauth.account.auth_backends.AuthenticationBackend",
)

ACCOUNT_EMAIL_REQUIRED = True

LOGIN_REDIRECT_URL = "/"
```

Here's `urls.py`

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',

  url(r'^accounts/', include('allauth.urls')),

)
```

I haven't made any other `django-allauth` settings.
I saw the [docs](http://django-allauth.readthedocs.org/en/latest/#providers) and couldn't find where to make the change.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

I found that the issue occurs because the nginx proxy, which sits in front of the python app server, sets the HTTP `Host` header to `localhost`.

So when `allauth` tries to do [`request.build_absolute_uri`](https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/http/request.py), `HTTP_HOST` is `localhost`.

So I set the Setting `proxy_set_header` in the [nginx configuration file](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule#proxy_set_header) which fixed the issue.

```
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
```

Also see [Facebook oauth authentication is redirecting to localhost instead of to my domain](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16494204/facebook-oauth-authentication-is-redirecting-to-localhost-instead-of-to-my-domai) for the same issue in a different avatar.

Comment: For some reason, this behaviour of using the `Host` header from the incoming request doesn't seem to be documented anywhere in the `django-allauth` docs.

Comment: @SatyajeetKanetkar Yes. I think I had to read the source to figure it out.